# Replace SimpleCursorAdapter with LoaderManager?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am using a listview to monitor my sqlite database ,this is the intial code that im using for it:

```
  mListView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);        




    mHelper = new MyDbHelperContacts(getActivity());
    mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", MyDbHelperContacts.COL_USERNAME,  
 MyDbHelperContacts.COL_REALNAME,MyDbHelperContacts.COL_IMAGE1, 
 MyDbHelperContacts.COL_IMAGE2, MyDbHelperContacts.COL_EMAIL};
    mCursor = mDb.query(MyDbHelperContacts.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, 
 null, null, null);
    String[] headers = new String[] {MyDbHelperContacts.COL_USERNAME,  
 MyDbHelperContacts.COL_REALNAME};


    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            mCursor,
             headers,
             new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},  
 0);        

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

as you see i use a Cursor and query the data base, and here is how i insert:

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(5);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_USERNAME, username);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_REALNAME, realname);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_IMAGE1, image1);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_IMAGE2, image2);
   cv.put(MyDbHelperContacts.COL_EMAIL, email);
   mDb.insert(MyDbHelperContacts.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
   mCursor.requery();
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

the way that im using SimpleCursorAdapter, its not depcerated, but when i read about LoaderManager, it says loadermanager works in background just like asynctask, will my code usage here cause problems later? if so how shoul i initialize this:

```
 @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
//Uri uriexample = Customer.CONTENT_URI;
// i dont want to use Uri ofcourse  
     return new CursorLoader(this, uriexample, null, null, null, null);
}
```

so works with my own cursor?
thank you very much

Comment: use a custom ContentProvider

Comment: fine, but will using content values for adding cause any problems?

Comment: what problems are you talking about?

Comment: locking UI, not responding , totally performance problems

Comment: performance problems when inserting ONE record? nope...